# Cleanest way to declare a tuple of one string

Tags: python

Declaring a tuple of one string using the function produces one element per item in the string

```
(Pdb) tuple('VERSION',)
('V', 'E', 'R', 'S', 'I', 'O', 'N')
```

Declaring a tuple using commas feels like a side effect and I feel like is easy to miss.

```
(Pdb) ('VERSION',)
('VERSION',)
```

Is there a cleaner way to make a declaration like this?

For context I'm using a tuple of tuples and I'm iterating on all of the individual values. Rather than special case the single values I'm just making them a tuple of one item.

Edit: I see I was unclear about this.

I don't personally like the declaration of `('VERSION',)` so I tried

```
(Pdb) tuple('VERSION',)
('V', 'E', 'R', 'S', 'I', 'O', 'N')`
```

And found that the function declaration to have this behavior.

I was interested to find that you could enclose the tuple declaration with a tuple declaration and that works.

```
(Pdb) tuple(['VERSION'])
('VERSION',)
(Pdb) tuple(('VERSION',))
('VERSION',)
```

Comment: It's not a side effect; commas are *how* you define a tuple, period. `x, y` is also a tuple; the parentheses in `(x, y)` are only needed if the comma could be mistaken for another use (e.g., separating arguments in a function call).

Comment: You could use `tuple(["string"])` but that wouldn't be as efficient as just making a tuple the regular way

Comment: @Sayse that's not efficient and best practice btw

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi - Thats basically what i wrote

Comment: Function call argument lists allow (for some reason) a trailing comma, so `tuple('Version')` and `tuple('Version',)` are equivalent. The extra parentheses make the comma part of an expression, rather than part of the argument list.

Comment: _Declaring a tuple using commas feels like a side effect_ Under what definition of a side effect?

Comment: Terminology note: Python *doesn't have variable declarations*.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's really a good question, how should we distinguish the difference between two parentheses and a tuple with one element, look at the following example :

```
>>> a = (1)+(2)
>>> a
3
>>> b = (1,)+(2,)
>>> b
(1, 2)
```

it's the beauty of the syntax of python, that `,` may look like an extra thing, but it makes difference `()` operator and `tuples`. so you should use it when you create a tuple with length one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the tuple by name, you can write `tuple(['foo'])` or `tuple(('foo',))`.

The `tuple` constructor takes an iterable, and, unless it's already a tuple, makes its elements the tuple's elements. There's no way around that.

The *idiomatic* way to define a 1-tuple is `(`foo`,)`. I personally find the `,)` a sign which is hard to miss, but tastes vary.

For ultimate clarity, just make your own function:

```py
def tu(value):
  return (value,)
```

Now you can `tu('foo')` and get a 1-tuple.

Comment: I wouldn't call an arbitrarily named function whose definition you need to find to see what it does "ultimate clarity".

Comment: Opinion-based questions are generally off-topic here. I just outlined the possibilities; I suppose there are no other less-contrived ways to create a tuple. Choose your poison.